# ImportError even after placing modules correctly

Tags: python

I have a project with couple of modules residing directly inside my project root and a drivers directory where I placed main.py which imports some of my modules.
When I execute main.py from my root directory i.e,. python drivers/main.py
It is supposed to load my modules as I'am on correct path.

But strangely it throws ImportError saying unable to import modules.
I have checked all my modules and they have **init**.py 
I also did os.getcwd() which is showing my project root path

Can someone please tell me where can I possibly go wrong?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `main.py` is in the `drivers` folder, and the modules you're trying to import are in the same directory that the `drivers` folder is in?

Comment: How are you importing the modules in your main.py and what does the hierarchy of your project look like?

Comment: @mattm: No they are placed in the project root which is execution path

Comment: Is this project root included in `sys.path`?

Comment: @DavidReeve: Actually I've tried showing my structure in question..but it was difficult to format in this stack text box. ProjectRoot has 3 directories 2 are modules and 1 drivers folder. I'am trying to import one of my modules in drivers/main.py

Comment: Do your modules all have `__init__.py` files?

Comment: @mattm actually I'am executing it from the project root directory itself... I don't think putting sys.path in my code is neccesary... I have a work around when I move drivers/main.py to project root... it's working fine there.. but for some reason I want solution in this way

Comment: @DavidReeve : Yes they do. I've also tried putting __init__.py in drivers folder but that didn't work :(

Comment: It doesn't matter where you are executing it from. What matters is where the `.py` file is that is trying to import the module. It works when you move `main.py` to the root because now the modules are next to `main.py`.

Comment: Have you tried using . to import the modules? i.e. `import .mymodule`

Comment: I get this error ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modules you are trying to import either have to be next to the `.py` file you are importing them in,  or the directory where these modules live need to be added to `PYTHONPATH`.

See: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: Adding to it... It can also be in the path where you are executing from

Comment: Can you please clarify, I do not know what you are trying to say?

Comment: I think you are thinking of "executing from" as what path you are in when you call `drivers/main.py`. But what it means is "when an `import` statement is encountered, what is the current execution path?". In your situation, it would be `drivers/`.

Comment: No It would be my projectroot. I also mentioned in the question that when I tried to see os.getcwd() in main.py it is printing my project root only.moreover I had worked like this before... I just wanted to know what could be the other possible ways it can go wrong

Comment: I'm sorry but that's just plainly wrong. The directory you are in at the command line when you call whatever `.py` file is totally irrelevant. What matters is where the `.py` file _is_.

Comment: @SatishReddy the current working directory is _not_ the same thing as the execution path.

Comment: Thank you matt. I got my mistake... when I print sys.path it shows drivers but not my project root.. I wanted to vote it up but unfortunately couldn't due to lack of stack credits as I new to stack